# Where does Active Directory Explorer (ADExplorer.exe) store its 'Favorites'?

Tags: active-directory-explorer

Anybody know where Active Directory Explorer (ADExplorer.exe) store its 'Favorites'?

Answer (score 2):

[Active Directory Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx) stores favorites in the registry.  They can be found under the key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MSDART\Active Directory Explorer
```

Each favorite is a new string value with the name `Favorite-FavName` where *FavName* is the name of the favorite.